# How to write a remove function for a tree using a given string list in f#?

Tags: data-structures, f#, tree, f#-3.0

I am trying to write a 'remove' function that can delete a tree type based on the value of a given string list but I am not getting something right when I use the function, example:

Code:

```
type Tree = Leaf of string | Branch of (string * Tree) list

let rec remove (p :string list) (tree: Tree) :Tree =
  match p, tree with
  | a::b, y  -> 
    match y with
    | Leaf(n) when a = n -> Leaf("") 
    | Branch[(x, p)] when a = x ->  Branch[("",  remove b p)]
    | _     -> remove b y
  | [], y    -> tree
```

Test:

```
remove ["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"]  
  (Branch [("6", Branch [("1", Branch [("2", Branch [("13", Leaf "4")])])])])
```

gives the answer

```
Branch [("6", Branch [("1", Branch [("2", Branch [("13", Leaf "4")])])])]
```

instead of

```
(Branch [("6", Branch [(" ", Branch [(" ", Branch [("13", Leaf " ")])])])])
```

If anyone can help advise me it would be great because I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing this is that you are iterating over the list and the tree at the same time. This means that your code can only work if the numbers appear in the tree in the same order in which they appear in the list of items to be removed.

If this is what you actually want, you can add one case to your function to make it work:

```
let rec remove (p :string list) (tree: Tree) :Tree =
  match p, tree with
  | a::b, y  -> 
    match y with
    | Leaf(n) when a = n -> Leaf("") 
    | Branch[(x, p)] when a = x ->  Branch[("",  remove b p)]
    | Branch[(x, p)] -> Branch[(x, remove (a::b) p)] // Added this line!
    | _     -> remove b y
  | [], y    -> tree
```

The added line handles the case when you find a branch that has a number not at the beginning of the list - so we keep the branch as is and continue removing numbers from the sub-tree.

That said, I imagine you probably want to remove the nodes regardless of the order of the elements in the list. You can do this by using something like `List.contains` to check if a branch should be removed:

```
let rec remove (p :string list) (tree: Tree) :Tree =
  match tree with
  | Leaf(n) when List.contains n p -> Leaf("") 
  | Branch[(x, sub)] when List.contains x p ->  Branch[("",  remove p sub)]
  | Branch[(x, sub)] ->  Branch[(x, remove p sub)]
```

Note that this code is still missing a case for branch with multiple sub-trees, so this is something you'll need to add, but hopefully, the example points you in the right direction!